# Find average start time of a process of past 30 days in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, average

```
|Date       |class  |process_start_date_time
2022-07-05  English 2022-07-05 01:03:08.883
2022-07-06  English 2022-07-07 02:05:08.000
2022-07-07  English 2022-07-07 05:00:08.000
2022-07-05  Hindi   2022-07-06 10:00:08.000
2022-07-07  Hindi   2022-07-08 11:00:08.000
```

The above table is an example, I am trying to get average start time of a class for example:
We should be able to conclude for any date the average time when English class starts is 03:00 (just a rough time)

I have tried below SQL code:

```
convert(varchar(8), Cast(DateAdd(ms, AVG(CAST(DateDiff( ms, '00:00:00', cast(process_start_date_timeas time)) AS BIGINT)), '00:00:00' ) as Time )) as Average_Process_Time
```

But I want to select a range of dates (past 30 days) to find the average.

Can someone please help?

Comment: add the table you want as output

Answer (score -1):

Its difficult when working with dates. Its better to convert it to milliseconds after 1. Jan 1970.

1. Convert dates to Unix timestamp
2. Get time after date start: 00:00
3. Calculate average (may be that a mean is better fitted?)
4. Only do that where date is not older than 30 days

`SELECT AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(process_start_time_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE)) FROM table_name WHERE Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()`

Comment: Since I am using SQL server, guess I cant use UNIX_TIMESTAMP.
Error: 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' is not a recognized built-in function name.